# Missing required parameter for [Route: rolespermissions.update] [URI: rolespermissions/{rolespermission}] [Missing parameter: rolespermission]

Tags: laravel

Why am I getting the following error message:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: rolespermissions.update] [URI:
> rolespermissions/{rolespermission}] [Missing parameter:
> rolespermission]. (View:
> C:\laragon\www\idoc4\resources\views\rolespermissions\edit.blade.php)

The code for my controller is as follows:

```
  public function edit(Role $role)
    {
        $permissions = Permission::all();
        
        // return view('rolespermissions.edit',compact('role', 'permissions'));
        return view('rolespermissions.edit',[ 'role' => $role, 'permisssions' => $permissions]);
    }
```

My blade code is as follows:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('rolespermissions.index') }}"> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form action="{{ route('rolespermissions.update',$role->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf

        @method('PUT')
        <div class="card card-primary m-1" >
            <div class="card-header">
                Kemaskini Peranan Kebenaran
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                {{ $role->name }}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
                            <input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{$permission->id}}" />{{$permission->name}}<br />
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>

               

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: The `$role->id` is null. check to sure the `$role` has value before sending data to the blade file.

Comment: I think `$role` might be null in edit method as well. If it is null. Check for explicit route bindings.

Comment: Solve the problem, that for the help. Before this it was sending null

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the controller as follows: Correct it was sending null before this

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);
        // dd($role);
        $permissions = Permission::all();
        
        // return view('rolespermissions.edit',compact('role', 'permissions'));
        return view('rolespermissions.edit',[ 'role' => $role, 'permissions' => $permissions]);
    }
```